# How to simulate collecting in nested loop for

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to create a list of pairs `(a . b)` with `1 < a < b <= n` up to `n`, e.g. `n = 5`:

```
((2 . 3) (2 . 4) (3 . 4) (2 . 5) (3 . 5) (4 . 5))
```

*(The order of the pairs is not critical.)*

I came up with the code

```
(defun create-pairs (upper-bound)
  (loop for i from 3 to upper-bound
        for j from 2 to (1- upper-bound)
          collecting (cons j i)))
```

but that doesn't do what I wanted

```
* (create-pairs 5)
((2 . 3) (3 . 4) (4 . 5))
```

since the loops are incrementing at the same time.

Therefore I tried this

```
(defun create-pairs (upper-bound)
  (loop for i from 3 to upper-bound do
    (loop for j from 2 to (1- upper-bound)
      collecting (cons j i))))
```

with the result:

```
* (create-pairs 5)

NIL
```

I don't remember where but I read that it's not possible to use `collecting` in constructs like my second try.

So how do I get the result I want to have? Isn't it possible to solve this with `loop for`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there - you just need to [accumulate](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_ac.htm) the results of the inner [`loop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_a.htm):

```
(defun create-pairs (upper-bound)
  (loop for i from 3 to upper-bound nconc
    (loop for j from 2 below i
      collect (cons j i))))
(create-pairs 5)
==> ((2 . 3) (2 . 4) (3 . 4) (2 . 5) (3 . 5) (4 . 5))
```

Comment: perfect, especially thanks for the link!